# AWS CDK Allow Lambda to write items into AWS DynamoDB

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I try to build a lambda function that is able to add items into dynamo db. The lambda is accessed via API Gateway and it's protected via user pool. However, every time I try to add something into the database, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PutItem operation: User: arn:aws:sts::{account-id}:assumed-role/SoccerTipGameInfrastructu-fastApiLambdaServiceRole-121EKY67BICBU/SoccerTipGameInfrastructureS-fastApiLambda1F147E7F-Zvo7rWg8oFGY is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:{account-id}:table/teams because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action
```

this is my CDK file:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import * as apiGateway from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';
import * as ddb from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb';
import * as cog from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-cognito'
import { BillingMode } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb';
import { table } from 'console';
import * as cognito from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-cognito';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam'

export class AppInfrastructureStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Cognito Userpool
    const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, 'userpool', {
      // not relevant
    });

    userPool.addDomain('CognitoDomain', {
      // not relevant
    });

    const clientReadAttributes = new cognito.ClientAttributes()
    .withStandardAttributes({
      // not relevant
    })
    .withCustomAttributes(...['isAdmin']);

    const clientWriteAttributes = new cognito.ClientAttributes()
      .withStandardAttributes({
          // not relevant
        })
      .withCustomAttributes(...[]);

    const userPoolClient = new cognito.UserPoolClient(this, 'userpool-client', {
      // not relevant
    });

    // DB Table
    const teamsTable = new ddb.Table(this, "teams", {
      partitionKey: {name: "team_id", type: ddb.AttributeType.STRING},
      billingMode: ddb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
    });


    // Base Layer with fastapi installed
    const fastApiBaseLayer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, "fastApiBaseLayer", {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambda_base_layer/layer.zip"),
      compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
    });

    // Lambda function
    const fastApiLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "fastApiLambda", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("../app"),
      handler: "main.handler",
      layers: [fastApiBaseLayer],
      environment: {
        TEAMS_TABLE_NAME: "teams",
        COGNITO_PUBLIC_KEY: // not relevant
      }
    });

    const authorizer = new apiGateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(this, 'userPoolAuth', {
      cognitoUserPools: [userPool]
    })

    // Api Gateway
    const fastApiApiGateway = new apiGateway.RestApi(this, "fastApiApiGateway", {
      restApiName: "fastApiApiGateway",
      defaultMethodOptions: {
        authorizationType: apiGateway.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
        authorizer
      }
    });

    // Lambda to ApiGateway
    const lambdaApiIntegration = new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(fastApiLambda);

    fastApiApiGateway.root.addProxy({
      defaultIntegration: lambdaApiIntegration
    });

    teamsTable.grantReadWriteData(fastApiLambda);
  }
}
```

Can you help me with that?

I already tried to add permission via `iam.PolicyStatement` but that didn't work out as well.

Comment: It's difficult to help when you redact the exception. Remove your accountId but leave the other elements.

Comment: @LeeHannigan sorry, didn't knew it was relevant - added information

Comment: That clears up the issue, added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error indicates you are trying to write to the DynamoDB table named `teams`, but your CDK code does not create a table with this name:

```
    const teamsTable = new ddb.Table(this, "teams", {
      partitionKey: {name: "team_id", type: ddb.AttributeType.STRING},
      billingMode: ddb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
    });
```

If you have a look at the CDK documentation for ddb.Table, you'll find that you specified the CloudFormation Id:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb.Table.html

If you want to resolve the table name, you'll have to pass that into your lambda function as an environment variable rather than the string you have in there:

```
    const fastApiLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "fastApiLambda", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("../app"),
      handler: "main.handler",
      layers: [fastApiBaseLayer],
      environment: {
        TEAMS_TABLE_NAME: teamsTable.tableName,
        COGNITO_PUBLIC_KEY: // not relevant
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Create your table by defining a tableName and not rely on CFN naming:

```
const teamsTable = new ddb.Table(this, "teams", {
      partitionKey: {name: "team_id", type: ddb.AttributeType.STRING},
      billingMode: ddb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
      tableName: "teams"
    });
```

Another way to ensure you don't run into those is not to hardcode variables, so you should pass the table name from the construct to your Lambda env variables as code:

```
const fastApiLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "fastApiLambda", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("../app"),
      handler: "main.handler",
      layers: [fastApiBaseLayer],
      environment: {
        TEAMS_TABLE_NAME: teamsTable.tableName,
        COGNITO_PUBLIC_KEY: // not relevant
      }
    });
```